# Time out when creating a site collection

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-api

I am trying to create a site collection programmatically. 
It has worked for about 6 months, but after the servers have been updated (various patches) it doesn’t work anymore (we have 3 servers: 1 development, 1 test, 1 production). It is still working in my development environment which hasn’t been updated, but not on the two others.
I don’t receive any error messages, it just hangs at the code that is supposed to add the site collection (see code below).
I am using Windows Server 2003 R2  and Sharepoint 2007 (version 12.0.0.6421 ).
It doesn’t give me any errors, it just hangs until Internet Explorer comes with a “request timed out” response.
If I try and debug the code, the code just stops there and nothing happens. No error messages or anything.

```
    public static string CreateSPAccountSite(string siteName)
    {
        string url = "";
        SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
        {
            SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
            using (SPSite siteCollectionOuter = new SPSite(web.Site.ID))
            {
                SPWebApplication webApp = siteCollectionOuter.WebApplication;
                SPSiteCollection siteCollection = webApp.Sites;

                SPSite site = siteCollection.Add("sites/" + siteName, siteName, "Auto generated Site collection.", 1033, "STS#0", siteCollectionOuter.Owner.LoginName, siteCollectionOuter.Owner.Name, siteCollectionOuter.Owner.Email); //Hangs here                    site.PortalName = "Portal";
                site.PortalUrl = mainUrl; // https://www.ourdomain.net
                url = site.Url;
            }
        });

        return url; //Should be "https://www.outdomain.net/sites/siteName"

    }
```

Comment: Well, I can't see anything wrong with your code (though I'd have used the context outside the elevate block to get the SPSite ID). Have you changed your farm configuration at all? Access to the config database? Though I'd expect an exception, not just timeout.